# How to enhance a script for look ups from multiple CSV files

Tags: python, bash, command-line, scripting, text-processing

I need to enhance my below script, which takes an input file that contains almost a million unique lines. Against each line, it has different values in 3 lookup files which I intend to add in my output as comma separated values.

The below script works fine, but it takes hours to finish the job. I am looking for a real fast solution which would also be less heavy on the system.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r ONT
do
{

ONSTATUS=$(grep "$ONT," lookupfile1.csv | cut -d" " -f2)
CID=$(grep "$ONT." lookupfile3.csv | head -1 | cut -d, -f2)
line1=$(grep "$ONT.C2.P1," lookupfile2.csv | head -1 | cut -d"," -f2,7 | sed 's/ //')
line2=$(grep "$ONT.C2.P2," lookupfile2.csv | head -1 | cut -d"," -f2,7 | sed 's/ //')
echo "$ONT,$ONSTATUS,$CID,$line1,$line2" >> BUwithPO.csv
} & 
done < inputfile.csv
```

inputfile.csv contains the lines shown below:

```
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT1
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT10
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT34
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT39
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT100
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT57
```

lookupfile1.csv contains:

```
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT100, Down,Locked,No
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT57, Up,Unlocked,Yes
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT1, Down,Unlocked,No
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT34, Up,Unlocked,Yes
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT39, Up,Unlocked,Yes
```

lookupfile2.csv contains:

```
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT34.C2.P1, +123125302766,REG,DigitMap,Unlocked,_media_BNT,FD_BSFU.xml,
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT57.C2.P1, +123125334019,REG,DigitMap,Unlocked,_media_BNT,FD_BSFU.xml,
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT57.C2.P2, +123125334819,REG,DigitMap,Unlocked,_media_BNT,FD_BSFU.xml,
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT100.C2.P11, +123128994019,REG,DigitMap,Unlocked,_media_ANT,FD_BSFU.xml,
```

lookupfile3.csv contains:

```
343OL5:LT1.PON1.ONT100.SERV1,12-654-0330
343OL5:LT1.PON1.ONT100.C1.P1,12-654-0330
343OL5:LT7.PON8.ONT75.SERV1,12-664-1186
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT34.C1.P1.FLOW1,12-530-2766
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT57.C1.P1.FLOW1,12-533-4019
```

the output is:

```
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT57, Up,Unlocked,Yes,12-533-4019,+123125334019,FD_BSFU.xml,+123125334819,FD_BSFU.xml
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT34, Up,Unlocked,Yes,12-530-2766,+123125302766,FD_BSFU.xml,
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT1, Down,Unlocked,No,,,
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT100, Down,Locked,No,,,
343OL5:LT1.PN1.ONT10,,,,
225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT39, Up,Unlocked,Yes,,,
```

Comment: Can you describe where [python-textprocessing] is in your question? I see only `bash` and unix tools

Comment: WOW, you are spawning at minimum 17-subshells calling utilities within your  *command substitutions* tying the outputs and inputs together with 9-pipes. No wonder its slow. Think about it. For each iteration (in the million you have) you call 13-utilities within 4-command substitution plus the pipes. Reducing that by using built-ins, etc.. should be the main focus.

Comment: Also, is the line order of the output important? Does it need to be in the same order you have shown, or could a line beginning with `343OL5` be the first line?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin order is not important, but columns should be in same order as described above. can you suggest some alternate with built-ins?

Comment: @AlexYu I have added this tag so if someone can suggest a python approach

Comment: @Ibraheem - then in that case, it will be hard to beat the `awk` solution. Have you tried what @tshiono posted?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I just replied, it seems to have something missing in awk solution, I even added `#!/usr/bin/awk ` and ran again and then it gave an error  `awk: 1: unexpected character '.'`

Comment: Oh, `gensub` is a function unique to GNU `awk`. I suspect that is why you are receiving the error. There will be a workaround using regular `awk` functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you'll see, the bottleneck will be executing `grep` within the loop multiple times. You can increase the efficiency by creating a look-up table with associative arrays.
If `awk` is available, please try the following:

**[Update]**

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
FILENAME=="lookupfile1.csv" {
    sub(",$", "", $1);
    onstatus[$1] = $2
}
FILENAME=="lookupfile2.csv" {
    split($2, a, ",")
    if (sub("\\.C2\\.P1,$", "", $1)) line1[$1] = a[1]","a[6]
    else if (sub("\\.C2\\.P2,$", "", $1)) line2[$1] = a[1]","a[6]
}
FILENAME=="lookupfile3.csv" {
    split($0, a, ",")
    if (match(a[1], ".+\\.ONT[0-9]+")) {
        ont = substr(a[1], RSTART, RLENGTH)
        cid[ont] = a[2]
    }
}
FILENAME=="inputfile.csv" {
    print $0","onstatus[$0]","cid[$0]","line1[$0]","line2[$0]
}
' lookupfile1.csv lookupfile2.csv lookupfile3.csv inputfile.csv > BUwithPO.csv
```

**{EDIT]**

If you need to specify absolute paths to the files, please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '
FILENAME ~ /lookupfile1.csv$/ {
    sub(",$", "", $1);
    onstatus[$1] = $2
}
FILENAME ~ /lookupfile2.csv$/ {
    split($2, a, ",")
    if (sub("\\.C2\\.P1,$", "", $1)) line1[$1] = a[1]","a[6]
    else if (sub("\\.C2\\.P2,$", "", $1)) line2[$1] = a[1]","a[6]
}
FILENAME ~ /lookupfile3.csv$/ {
    split($0, a, ",")
    if (match(a[1], ".+\\.ONT[0-9]+")) {
        ont = substr(a[1], RSTART, RLENGTH)
        cid[ont] = a[2]
    }
}
FILENAME ~ /inputfile.csv$/ {
    print $0","onstatus[$0]","cid[$0]","line1[$0]","line2[$0]
}
' /path/to/lookupfile1.csv /path/to/lookupfile2.csv /path/to/lookupfile3.csv /path/to/inputfile.csv > /path/to/BUwithPO.csv
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried above, and it says `awk: line 20: function gensub never defined`

Comment: I'm afraid your `awk` version is not updated. Okay, I'll modify the script without using the function.

Comment: I've updated my answer by substituting the `gensub()` function. I hope it'll work now.

Comment: @Ole How can I run this script using parallel?

Comment: if I want to use this awk script in a crontab, how the FILENAME variable will behave, as I see crontabs mostly need absolute paths, plus not sure how AWK will interprete if the file names were given in variables as I don't want to hard code the file names in the script

Comment: I agree that it is not a good manner to embed filenames in the code.
I've updated my answer with a small improvement by matching the filenames
with regex. Now you can specify the absolute paths to the files by just
modifying the last line (argument list), although you still need to
keep the filenames as is.
Regarding the `parallel`, I'm afraid `GNU parallel` may not be applied
for the application. If you still need to accelerate the execution,
please let me know the current benchmark and target execution time.
I know there is room for improvement in my code. BR.

Comment: there is no target as such as I am down to less than 10 seconds now compared to my previous script which would take at least half hour to finish. 
so it is super fast already, but if you can share the improvement for my learning, I will really appreciate that

Comment: One possible improvement is to put `next` statement at the end of each
`FILENAME ~ { }` block (just before the closing curly brace).
It skips the following filename matchings and will slightly increase the
efficiency.
Another possibility is to tune up regular expressions used in `sub()` and
`match()`. It requires try-and-error type of approach.
These improvements are optional if the script works fast enough because they
will add codes and may lose maintainability. It will be a common issue of
cost-effectiveness.

Comment: I'll try the next statement and let you know the outcome

Comment: I'm seeing some problems with the output data. It seems if the values are not found in the lookup files, especially the lookupfile2 which has two values to lookup from. If line1 isn't matched and line2 does, it prints line 2 in place of line1. I want to put empty field (or 0) for the values not found. I tried `else line[$1]=0","0` after both `if` statements but still it is not producing the desired output. Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay, would you please update your question with adding (better not to overwrite the existing texts) examples which cause the problem as well as the expected result for my better understanding? Sorry for taking your time. BR.

Answer (score 4):

If as you have indicated in the comments, you are unable to use the solution provided by @tshiono due to lacking `gensub` provided by GNU `awk`, you can replace `gensub` with two calls to `sub` with a temporary variable to accomplish trimming the needed suffix.

**Example:**

```
awk '
FILENAME=="lookupfile1.csv" {
    sub(",$", "", $1);
    onstatus[$1] = $2
}
FILENAME=="lookupfile2.csv" {
    split($2, a, ",")
    if (sub("\\.C2\\.P1,$", "", $1)) line1[$1] = a[1]","a[6]
    else if (sub("\\.C2\\.P2,$", "", $1)) line2[$1] = a[1]","a[6]
}
FILENAME=="lookupfile3.csv" {
    split($0, a, ",")
#     ont = gensub("(\\.ONT[0-9]+).*", "\\1", 1, a[1])
    sfx = a[1]
    sub(/^.*[.]ONT[^.]*/, "", sfx)
    sub(sfx, "", a[1])
#     cid[ont] = a[2]
    cid[a[1]] = a[2]
}
FILENAME=="inputfile.csv" {
    print $0","onstatus[$0]","cid[$0]","line1[$0]","line2[$0]
}
' lookupfile1.csv lookupfile2.csv lookupfile3.csv inputfile.csv > BUwithPO.csv
```

I have commented out the use of `gensub` in the portion related to `FILENAME=="lookupfile3.csv"` and replaced the `gensub` expression with two calls to `sub` using `sfx` (suffix) as the temporary variable.

Give it a try and let me know if you are able to use that.

Comment: it is working as expected, except for a few columns being here and there out of order, which could possibly be due to the lookupfiles having the same disorder, I will try to improve the lookupfiles, thank you for the help but I am not able to vote due to lack of reputation points needed for it :)

Comment: No worries, I'm glad it helped. `awk` should be *orders of magnitude* faster than your shell script `:)`

Comment: Indeed it is, :-) I'm looking for some python alternate or a database, but I need to learn them first as am just a beginner in scripts so.. will need some time

Answer (score 3):

#### Perl solution

The following script is similar to the `awk` solution but written in Perl.
Save it as `filter.pl` and make it executable.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %lookup1;
my %lookup2_1;
my %lookup2_2;
my %lookup3;

while( <> ) {
    if ( $ARGV eq 'lookupfile1.csv' ) {
        # 225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT34, Up,Unlocked,Yes
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
        if (/^([^,]+),\s*(.*)$/) {
            $lookup1{$1} = $2;
        }
    } elsif ( $ARGV eq 'lookupfile2.csv' ) {
        # 225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT34.C2.P1, +123125302766,REG,DigitMap,Unlocked,_media_BNT,FD_BSFU.xml,
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ 
        if (/^(.+ONT\d+)\.C2\.P1,\s*([^,]+),(?:[^,]+,){4}([^,]+)/) {
            $lookup2_1{$1} = "$2,$3";
        } elsif (/^(.+ONT\d+)\.C2\.P2,\s*([^,]+),(?:[^,]+,){4}([^,]+)/) {
            $lookup2_2{$1} = "$2,$3";
        }
    } elsif ( $ARGV eq 'lookupfile3.csv' ) {
        # 225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT34.C1.P1.FLOW1,12-530-2766
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^
        if (/^(.+ONT\d+)[^,]+,\s*(.*)$/) {
            $lookup3{$1} = $2;
        }
    } else { # assume 'inputfile.csv'
        no warnings 'uninitialized'; # because not all keys ($_) have values in the lookup tables
        # 225OL0:LT1.PN1.ONT34
        chomp;
        print "$_,$lookup1{$_},$lookup3{$_},$lookup2_1{$_},$lookup2_2{$_}\n";        
    }
}
```

Execute it like so:

```
./filter.pl lookupfile{1,2,3}.csv inputfile.csv > BUwithPO.csv
```

It is important that the lookupfiles come first (as in the `awk` solutions, btw.) because
they build the four dictionaries (*hashes* in Perl parlance) `%lookup1`, `%lookup2_1`, etc.
and then the values from `inputfile.csv` are matched against those dictionaries.

Comment: +1; It is valuable to see the same thing done in another language, not only `awk` but also `perl`. It helps understanding what is happening.

Comment: Thanks, I tired Perl solution today and it also works as expected, I'll  run it some more times to do comparison between Perl and awk solutions provided here,